Type '{ locale: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<any>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]
I've decided to go with NextJS 15 for a new WebPage I'm creating, which is similar to one I did a few months ago but on NextJS 14.
In that old page I used to pass props to my components with an interface as params, but now I get the error on the title. This is the code I have. I've tried looking in the changelog page of NextJS 15 but I couldn't find anything. Here's my code.
export default function HomePage(
  {
    params: { locale },
  }: {
    params: { locale: string }
  },
) {

  setRequestLocale(locale)
  return (
    <>
      <Hero
        locale={locale}
      />
      <main>
        <MoreAboutUs
          locale={locale}
        />
        <OurClients />
        <Solutions />
        <RFID locale={locale} />
        <Consultoria />
        <Industry4 />
        <Contact />
      </main>
    </>
  )
}


In NextJS 15, to use the params, the props should be more like type Props = {  params: Promise<{ locale: string } > }  (similarly, if you have searchParams should be a Promise), and since it needs to be awaited, the component should be async, too.

There is also use function if you have React 19, maybe you can find the example here useful: https://dev.to/peterlidee/synchronous-and-asynchronous-searchparams-in-next-15-3c7a
